# how do you make a object bounce of a object with pygame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I have a program it's bouncing ball I'm using pygame .I have a rectangle and I can use the mouse to move it the only problem is when I try to make the ball bounce of that rectangle it doesn't bounce.It just stays there and the loop the ball is in keeps going on.I can't quit out of there either.I am using python 2.7.9.Here is my code.

```
import pygame,sys
class MovingBall:
    def __init__(self,color,x,y,r,speed):
        self.color=color
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.r=r
        self.speed=speed
        self.dx=1
        self.dy=1
    def move(self,w,h):
        while True:
            nx = self.x+self.dx*self.speed; #new x position of the center of the circle
            ny = self.y+self.dy*self.speed; #new y position of the center of the circle

            if (nx < self.r or nx > w-self.r):
                self.dx *= -1
            if (ny < self.r or ny > h-self.r):
                self.dy *= -1

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    endProgram = True
                    break;

            #if ( new circle is completely inside the screen )
            if ( ( nx >= self.r and nx <= w - self.r ) and ( ny >= self.r and ny <= h-self.r ) ):
                self.x=nx; self.y=ny;
                break;


            print self.dx, self.dy, h-self.r, nx, ny, self.x, self.y

BLACK    = (   0,   0,   0)
BLUE      = (   0,   0, 255)
WHITE    = ( 255, 255, 255)

w=800; h=500 #width and height of the screen

pygame.init()
size = (w,h)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode ( size )

all_balls=[\
            MovingBall((0, 0, 255), 150, 150, 45, 4), \
  #          MovingBall((0, 255, 0), 250, 250, 45, 6), \
    #        MovingBall((255, 255, 0), 250, 350, 45, 5), \
    #        MovingBall((255, 0, 211), 250, 350, 45, 6), \
    #      MovingBall((255, 0, 255), 250, 350, 25, 3), \
      #      MovingBall((255, 255, 0), 250, 350, 40, 4), \
        #    MovingBall((0,172 ,255), 250, 350, 30, 5), \
          #  MovingBall((255, 0, 255), 250, 350, 35, 6), \
       #     MovingBall((255, 0, 0), 250, 350, 45, 7), \
       #     MovingBall((0, 0, 255), 150, 150, 45, 2), \
      #      MovingBall((0, 255, 0), 250, 250, 45, 6), \
     #       MovingBall((255, 255, 0), 250, 350, 45, 7), \
     #       MovingBall((255, 0, 211), 250, 350, 45, 10), \
     #       MovingBall((255, 201, 255), 250, 350, 25, 11), \
     #       MovingBall((255, 255, 0), 250, 350, 40, 8), \
     #       MovingBall((0,172 ,255), 250, 350, 30, 7), \
        #    MovingBall((255, 62, 255), 250, 350, 35, 6), \
          #  MovingBall((255, 35 ,90), 250, 350, 45, 8), \
                        ]
x=0
y=480
#program speed controller
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

endProgram = False
while endProgram==False:
    #Event handling
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            endProgram = True

    #Draw graphics
    screen.fill ( WHITE )
    for ball in all_balls:
        #if ball.limit > 0:
        pygame.draw.circle ( screen, ball.color, [ball.x, ball.y], ball.r );
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    kick=180
    rect_x = mouse_pos[0]
    if mouse_pos[0] + 180 >= w:
        rect_x = w - kick
    if y + 18 >= h:
        y  = h-18
    bob = pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,(rect_x, y,kick,18))
    if mouse_pos[0] > 620:
        mouse_pos *= -1

    #print 'rect ', mouse_pos[0], y, kick,18
    pygame.display.flip();

    for ball in all_balls:
        if ball.x > rect_x and ball.x < rect_x + kick:
            ball.move(w,480)
        else:
            ball.move(w,h)
        if ball.y > y and ball.y < y + 18:
            ball.move(0,y)

        #print 'ball ', ball.x, ball.y

    #50 frames per seconds
    clock.tick (30);
pygame.quit();
```

here is what happens when I try to bounce it off that rectangle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4yvd.png)

Comment: Have you tried using sprites?

Comment: what is a sprite ?how can it help me?

Comment: https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/ChimpLineByLine.html or http://thepythongamebook.com/en:pygame:step014 may help

Comment: yes I have done that

Comment: If you know sprites, then you can use it by blitting the circle on a surface and using sprites for updating and drawing that surface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the game gets stuck in the `move` method's while loop, because the ball is too deep inside of the paddle and can not move out of the colliding position. So the y-velocity (`self.dy`) keeps switching between 1 and -1 and the ball and the complete program get stuck.

You can check if the `self.dy` speed is negative and then set `self.y` or `ny` to a non-colliding position above the paddle, e.g.:

```
if ny < self.r or ny > h-self.r:
    self.dy *= -1
    if self.dy < 0:
        ny = h-self.r
```

It seems to me that the program can be simplified with [`pygame.Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)s (you're not using real circles anyway at the moment) and the while loop is probably unnecessary.